# Decoding Polkadot/Kusama transactions in Rust

Tags: subxt, decode, scale

I would like to inspect transactions (extrinsics) in a given block to potentially:

- Find different types of transactions and their parameters
- Look through all transactions included in the block and act on them based on type, sender etc.

So far I am able to query the block using `subtx` and see all transactions in raw form. I do not know how can I decode them to Rust types and act on them:

```rust
#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "../specs/kusama.spec.scale")]
pub mod kusama_client {}

...

    let api = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url(rpc_url)
        .await.unwrap();

    let block = api.rpc().block(None).await.unwrap().unwrap();

    for tx in block.block.extrinsics {
        println!("tx: {:?}", tx);

        // TODO: Decode transactions and act on them based on types etc...
        // ex. ImOnline etc...
    }
```

I know that the transactions are SCALE encoded, but I do not know what to decode them to Rust types, I do not even know what Rust types to use (I assume those generated from metadata, but how do I find appropriate type to decode to?).

I would also like to do the similar thing with other construct such as offences:

```rust
   let offences_addr = kusama_client::storage().offences().reports_by_kind_index(offence_kind);

    let offences = api
        .storage()
        .at(None)
        .await.unwrap()
        .fetch(&offences_addr)
        .await.unwrap()
        .unwrap();

     // TODO: decode and inspect offences
```

I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction, or examples if such exists.

Comment: As a side note, where does the code generated from metadata (#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "...") end up? Is it possible to configure IDE to go to the definition etc?

Comment: `#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "...")]` doesn't generate code anywhere (ie like other macros, you can use `cargo expand` to see the generated output, but it's generated during compilation. You can use the CLI tool to generate code instead if preferred (ie run `subxt codegen` after `cargo install subxt-cli`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also, Subxt doesn't currently have a means to decode transactions, but you can obtain the bytes for each transaction back currently eg:

```rust
let extrinsics = api.blocks().at(hash).await?.body().await?.extrinsics();
for ext in extrinsics {
    let bytes = ext.bytes();
    // decode bytes
}
```

I've updated https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/issues/622 to go into more detail about what sort of interface Subxt could add here to this `ext` value.

While Subxt doesn't support it at the moment, you can manually look into how to decode the extrinsic bytes. Some pointers for this:

- Start by reading about the extrinsic format (eg see https://docs.substrate.io/reference/transaction-format/ or look at how Subxt encodes them starting at https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/a69b3e45e71b5f6c3fd4aeeb7a38353f989ad9ea/subxt/src/tx/tx_client.rs#L197)
- Once you've learned about the format of the extrinsic signature, you'll see that "extra" params are encoded as part of it. If you look into the node metadata you'll see that each "extra" param has a type ID assocaietd with it here, which describes the shape of it: https://github.com/paritytech/frame-metadata/blob/438a5b098bb9d5b5a09bdc5b68275b2c5e63a010/frame-metadata/src/v14.rs#L117
- You can use `scale-decode` to decode types from bytes based on their metadata description: https://github.com/paritytech/scale-decode/blob/9164b12da2949f74eef5c6f02ed4fe82a9dc9907/scale-decode/src/lib.rs#L177. `scale-decode` also provides a generic `Value` type that anything can decode into, and a Visitor thing that you can use to skip over bytes you just want to ignore, given the type ID that they should decode to.
- With all of that in mind, you can decode or skip over the signature portion of an extrinsic and are left with the pallet index, call index and then call data. You can look the call type up in the metadata given these indexes, and again get a type Id that you can pass to `scale-decode` to decode the call data into some type (either one of the statically generated types in Subxt or a Value type).

.. You can see why it's something that we should add to Subxt in any case, as there are a number of steps to it :)

Answer (score 2):

Subxt currently exposes only the bytes of the extrinsic to users.
We plan on adding support for decoding to a concrete type generated by the subxt macro.

In the meanwhile, polkadot-introspector [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-introspector/blob/558b606bdcd335b54dfd8daa7d4171e8a1c3d406/introspector/src/core/api/subxt_wrapper.rs#L423-L453) is decoding manually the extrinsics.

For example, polkadot-introspector is interested only in finding the `ParaInherent` event.

Steps to decode the `ParaInherent` events:

1. Obtain the extrinsic data ([example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-introspector/blob/558b606bdcd335b54dfd8daa7d4171e8a1c3d406/introspector/src/core/api/subxt_wrapper.rs#L434))

Extrinsics are encoded in memory as:

- Compact u32: Length of the extrinsic
- first byte: abbbbbbb (a = 0 for unsigned, 1 for signed, b = version)
- signature
- extrinsic data

Note: this makes the assumption that the `ParaInherent` is unsigned, please adjust this per your needs.

2. Decode the extrinsic date to `RuntimeCall` generated by subxt macro (may be similar to `kusama_client::runtime_types::kusama_runtime::RuntimeCall` for your use case)
3. Match and inspect data (ie `ParaInherent` data - similar to [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-introspector/blob/558b606bdcd335b54dfd8daa7d4171e8a1c3d406/introspector/src/core/api/subxt_wrapper.rs#L626-L635))

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that stumbles upon this now, it has been implemented in `subtx` since posting the question in https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/pull/929.

Example code:

```rust
use subxt::OnlineClient;
use subxt::PolkadotConfig;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let rpc_url = "wss://kusama-rpc.polkadot.io:443/";

    let api = OnlineClient::<PolkadotConfig>::from_url(rpc_url)
        .await.unwrap();
    let block = api.blocks().at_latest().await.unwrap();

    for extrinsic in block.body().await.unwrap().extrinsics().iter() {
        let extrinsic = extrinsic.expect("error getting extrinsic");
        println!("Extrinsic {}::{}", extrinsic.pallet_name().unwrap(), extrinsic.variant_name().unwrap());
        // Do whatever you want with the extrinsic...
    }
}
```

Tested with `subxt` version `^0.31`.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode extrinsic's and parse blocks with Libuptest:
https://uptest-sc.github.io/code/decode.html